# Excel VBA - Subscript out of range for variant variable assigned a range value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, runtime-error

When working with this array I get subscript out of range when trying to print it out.  I see the LBound is 1, and nTemp in the For loop = 1 in the first iteration.  Any guidance on what is wrong here?

```
copyArr = .Range(.Cells(1, moveRng.Column), .Cells(rowsUsed, moveRng.Column)).Value
Debug.Print vbTab & "copyArr range is " & LBound(copyArr) & " : " & UBound(copyArr)
For nTemp = LBound(copyArr) To UBound(copyArr)
Debug.Print vbTab & "copyArr(" & nTemp & ") = " & copyArr(nTemp)
Next nTemp
```

Here is a sample of the debug output prior to the error.

```
Found header 'Device Type' for moveRng at column # 6
Found header 'IP Address' for insertRng at column # 3
copyArr range is 1 : 3
```

Here are the variable declares

```
Dim searchRng As Range, moveRng As Range, insertRng As Range, targetRng As Range, copyArr As Variant
Dim sTemp As String, deleteAddr As String
Dim nTemp As Long, copyOffset As Long, insertOffset As Long, deleteOffset As Long, rowsUsed As Long
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `copyArr` is a 2D array, not a 1D array.

Comment: Thanks a ton @BigBen - add (nTemp, 1) solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

@BigBen should get credit for this.  Simple error with 1d vs 2d arrays.

```
Debug.Print vbTab & "copyArr(" & nTemp & ") = " & copyArr(nTemp, 1)
```

That solved it.